# 4x4 Skyscraper game solver

Tags: c++, performance

I made a skyscraper solver based on the [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5671d975d81d6c1c87000022/cpp) on Codewars.

To try to understand the problem you can try to solve a 4x4 Skyscraper [here](https://www.brainbashers.com/showskyscraper.asp?date=0122&size=4&diff=1). There are also instructions available.

Now on Codewars there are also more difficult katas were you have to solve [6x6](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5679d5a3f2272011d700000d) or even [7x7](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5917a2205ffc30ec3a0000a8) Skyscraper puzzles.

Why are they more difficult? You run your code against a set of hidden unit tests on the site. If you cannot execute all the unit tests in an certain amount of time you don't pass.

I know that 6x6 and 7x7 take a lot more time to solve than 4x4. This is because the permutations of the numbers increase not linear. Just take a look at the permutations for one row of the board:

- 4x4 ->   24
- 6x6 ->  720
- 7x7 -> 5040

I already tried to optimize my code as much as possible for speed. I'd like to here your opinion what else can be improved for the speed.

Also let me know if the code is readable and has bad practices.

My goal is to make a fast but still readable solution.

Please don't let me know any approaches to solve 6x6 and 7x7 I want to find a way here myself.

One side note. On Codewars the interface for 4x4 is not defined in modern C++ way but with int* and int**. I cannot change that:

```
int** SolvePuzzle (int *clues) {
  // my code here
}
```

But I wrapped it using `std::array`.

Also everything is in one file. No `Cpp` / `h` separation which is also an restriction from Codewars. I only included a small h to be able to run my unit tests locally.

The code:

**skyscrapers.h**

```
#ifndef SKYSCRAPER_H
#define SKYSCRAPER_H

int **SolvePuzzle(int *clues);

#endif
```

**skyscraper.cpp**

```
#include "skyscrapers.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>
#include <unordered_set>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Nopes {
public:
    Nopes(int size);

    void insert(int value);
    bool sizeReached() const;
    int missingNumberInSequence() const;

    bool contains(int value) const;

    bool isEmpty() const;

    // for debug print
    std::unordered_set<int> values() const;

private:
    int mSize;
    std::unordered_set<int> mValues;
};

Nopes::Nopes(int size) : mSize{size}
{
    assert(size > 0);
}

void Nopes::insert(int value)
{
    assert(value >= 1 && value <= mSize + 1);
    mValues.insert(value);
}

bool Nopes::sizeReached() const
{
    return mValues.size() == static_cast<std::size_t>(mSize);
}

int Nopes::missingNumberInSequence() const
{
    assert(sizeReached());
    int n = mValues.size() + 1;
    int projectedSum = (n + 1) * (n / 2);
    int actualSum = std::accumulate(mValues.begin(), mValues.end(), 0);
    return projectedSum - actualSum;
}

bool Nopes::contains(int value) const
{
    auto it = mValues.find(value);
    return it != mValues.end();
}

bool Nopes::isEmpty() const
{
    return mValues.empty();
}

std::unordered_set<int> Nopes::values() const
{
    return mValues;
}

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

enum class BorderPosition { top, right, bottom, left };

void nextDirection(BorderPosition &borderPosition)
{
    if (borderPosition == BorderPosition::left) {
        borderPosition = BorderPosition::top;
    }
    else {
        int dir = static_cast<int>(borderPosition);
        ++dir;
        borderPosition = static_cast<BorderPosition>(dir);
    }
}

void advanceToNextPosition(Point &point, BorderPosition borderPosition,
                           int clueIdx)
{
    if (clueIdx == 0) {
        return;
    }
    switch (borderPosition) {
    case BorderPosition::top:
        ++point.x;
        break;
    case BorderPosition::right:
        ++point.y;
        break;
    case BorderPosition::bottom:
        --point.x;
        break;
    case BorderPosition::left:
        --point.y;
        break;
    }
}

class BorderIterator {
public:
    BorderIterator(std::size_t boardSize);

    Point point() const;
    BorderPosition borderPosition() const;

    BorderIterator &operator++();

private:
    int mIdx = 0;
    std::size_t mBoardSize;
    Point mPoint{0, 0};
    BorderPosition mReadDirection{BorderPosition::top};
};

BorderIterator::BorderIterator(std::size_t boardSize) : mBoardSize{boardSize}
{
}

Point BorderIterator::point() const
{
    return mPoint;
}

BorderPosition BorderIterator::borderPosition() const
{
    return mReadDirection;
}

BorderIterator &BorderIterator::operator++()
{
    ++mIdx;
    if (mIdx != 0 && mIdx % mBoardSize == 0) {
        nextDirection(mReadDirection);
    }

    advanceToNextPosition(mPoint, mReadDirection, mIdx % mBoardSize);
    return *this;
}

struct Board {
    Board(int size);

    std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4> skyscrapers{};
    std::array<std::array<Nopes, 4>, 4> nopes;
};

Board::Board(int size)
    : nopes{{
          {Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}},
          {Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}},
          {Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}},
          {Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}, Nopes{size - 1}},
      }}
{
}

class Slice {
public:
    Slice(Board &board, const Point &startPoint, BorderPosition borderPosition,
          int clue);

    void insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper, std::size_t idx);
    void insertNope(int nope, std::size_t idx);

    int skyscraper(std::size_t idx) const;
    Nopes nopes(std::size_t idx) const;

    std::size_t size() const;

    int clue() const;

    bool isFull() const;

private:
    void addSkyscraperAndNopesFromClue();

    void addNopesAndSkyscrapersIfOneSkyscraperVisible();
    void addNopesIfTwoSkyscrapersVisible();
    void addNopesIfThreeSkyscrapersVisible();
    void addSkyscrapersIfAllSkyscrapersVisible();

    Point calcPosition(int idx) const;

    Board &mBoard;
    Point mStartPoint;
    BorderPosition mDirection;
    int mClue;
    std::size_t mBoardSize;
    mutable bool mIsfull{false};
};

Slice::Slice(Board &board, const Point &startPoint,
             BorderPosition borderPosition, int clue)
    : mBoard{board}, mStartPoint{startPoint}, mDirection{borderPosition},
      mClue{clue}, mBoardSize{mBoard.skyscrapers.size()}
{
    assert(mClue >= 0 && mClue <= static_cast<int>(mBoardSize));
    if (mClue != 0) {
        addSkyscraperAndNopesFromClue();
    }
    /*
    Clue 1 and 4 cannot give us any more information so its not best to mark
    them as not existing for the follow up algorithm iterating over the slices
    */
    if (mClue != 2 && mClue != 3) {
        mClue = 0;
    }
}

void Slice::insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper, std::size_t idx)
{
    Point p = calcPosition(idx);
    mBoard.skyscrapers[p.y][p.x] = skyscraper;
}

void Slice::insertNope(int nope, std::size_t idx)
{
    Point p = calcPosition(idx);
    mBoard.nopes[p.y][p.x].insert(nope);

    if (mBoard.nopes[p.y][p.x].sizeReached()) {
        int missingSkyscraper =
            mBoard.nopes[p.y][p.x].missingNumberInSequence();
        insertSkyscraper(missingSkyscraper, idx);
    }
}

int Slice::skyscraper(std::size_t idx) const
{
    Point p = calcPosition(idx);
    return mBoard.skyscrapers[p.y][p.x];
}

Nopes Slice::nopes(std::size_t idx) const
{
    Point p = calcPosition(idx);
    return mBoard.nopes[p.y][p.x];
}

std::size_t Slice::size() const
{
    return mBoardSize;
}

int Slice::clue() const
{
    return mClue;
}

bool Slice::isFull() const
{
    if (mIsfull) {
        return mIsfull;
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
        if (skyscraper(i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    mIsfull = true;
    return mIsfull;
}

void Slice::addSkyscraperAndNopesFromClue()
{
    switch (mClue) {
    case 1:
        addNopesAndSkyscrapersIfOneSkyscraperVisible();
        break;
    case 2:
        addNopesIfTwoSkyscrapersVisible();
        break;
    case 3:
        addNopesIfThreeSkyscrapersVisible();
        break;
    case 4:
        addSkyscrapersIfAllSkyscrapersVisible();
        break;
    default:
        assert(false);
    }
}

void Slice::addNopesAndSkyscrapersIfOneSkyscraperVisible()
{
    insertSkyscraper(mBoardSize, 0);
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < size(); ++i) {
        if (skyscraper(i) == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        insertNope(mBoardSize, i);
    }
}

void Slice::addNopesIfTwoSkyscrapersVisible()
{
    if (skyscraper(0) == 0) {
        insertNope(mBoardSize, 0);
    }
    if (skyscraper(1) == 0) {
        insertNope(mBoardSize - 1, 1);
    }
}

void Slice::addNopesIfThreeSkyscrapersVisible()
{
    if (skyscraper(0) == 0) {
        insertNope(mBoardSize - 1, 0);
        insertNope(mBoardSize, 0);
    }
    if (skyscraper(1) == 0) {
        insertNope(mBoardSize, 1);
    }
}

void Slice::addSkyscrapersIfAllSkyscrapersVisible()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
        insertSkyscraper(i + 1, i);
    }
}

Point Slice::calcPosition(int idx) const
{
    Point point = mStartPoint;
    if (idx == 0) {
        return mStartPoint;
    }
    switch (mDirection) {
    case BorderPosition::top:
        point.y += idx;
        break;
    case BorderPosition::right:
        point.x -= idx;
        break;
    case BorderPosition::bottom:
        point.y -= idx;
        break;
    case BorderPosition::left:
        point.x += idx;
        break;
    }
    return point;
}

void debug_print(Board &board, const std::string &title = "")
{
    std::cout << title << '\n';
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < board.skyscrapers.size(); ++y) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < board.skyscrapers[y].size(); ++x) {
            if (board.skyscrapers[y][x] != 0) {
                std::cout << "V" << board.skyscrapers[y][x] << '\t';
            }
            else if (board.skyscrapers[y][x] == 0 &&
                     !board.nopes[y][x].isEmpty()) {
                auto nopes_set = board.nopes[y][x].values();
                std::vector<int> nopes(nopes_set.begin(), nopes_set.end());
                std::sort(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());

                for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nopes.size(); ++i) {
                    std::cout << nopes[i];

                    if (i == nopes.size() - 1) {
                        std::cout << '\t';
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << ',';
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cout << '\t';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void addMissingNopesFromKnownSkyscrapers(Slice &slice)
{
    std::vector<int> skyscrapers;
    skyscrapers.reserve(slice.size());

    bool foundNope = false;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < slice.size(); ++i) {
        if (slice.skyscraper(i) != 0) {
            skyscrapers.emplace_back(slice.skyscraper(i));
        }
        else if (!foundNope) {
            foundNope = true;
        }
    }
    if (!foundNope) {
        return;
    }
    if (skyscrapers.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < slice.size(); ++i) {
        if (slice.skyscraper(i) == 0) {
            for (const auto &skyscraper : skyscrapers) {
                slice.insertNope(skyscraper, i);
                if (slice.skyscraper(i) != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void guessSkyscraperOutOfNeighbourNopes(Slice &slice, int skyscraper)
{
    int idxWithNoSkyscaper = -1;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < slice.size(); ++i) {
        if (slice.skyscraper(i) != 0) {
            if (slice.skyscraper(i) == skyscraper) {
                return;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if (slice.nopes(i).contains(skyscraper)) {
            continue;
        }
        else { // existing node does not contain skyscaper
            if (idxWithNoSkyscaper != -1) {
                return;
            }
            idxWithNoSkyscaper = i;
        }
    }
    if (idxWithNoSkyscaper != -1) {
        slice.insertSkyscraper(skyscraper, idxWithNoSkyscaper);
    }
}

void guessSkyscrapersOutOfNeighbourNopes(Slice &slice)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < slice.size(); ++i) {
        guessSkyscraperOutOfNeighbourNopes(slice, i + 1);
    }
}

/*
requires:
clue = 3
3 4 x x | 3  ->  3 4 2 1 | 3
4 3 x x | 3  ->  4 3 1 2 | 3
*/
void guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsThreeAndLastTwoSkyscrapersKnown(Slice &slice)
{
    if (slice.skyscraper(3) == 0 || slice.skyscraper(2) == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (slice.skyscraper(3) == 3 && slice.skyscraper(2) == 4) {

        slice.insertSkyscraper(2, 1);
        slice.insertSkyscraper(1, 0);
    }
    else if (slice.skyscraper(3) == 4 && slice.skyscraper(2) == 3) {

        slice.insertSkyscraper(1, 1);
        slice.insertSkyscraper(2, 0);
    }
}

/*
requires
clue = 3
4 N3 X X | 3 -> 4 1 3 2 | 3
*/
void guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsThreeAndLastSkyscraperIsFourAndThirdNopeIsThree(
    Slice &slice)
{
    if (slice.skyscraper(3) != 4) {
        return;
    }
    if (!slice.nopes(2).contains(3)) {
        return;
    }
    slice.insertSkyscraper(1, 2);
    slice.insertSkyscraper(3, 1);
    slice.insertSkyscraper(2, 0);
}

/*
requires:
clue = 2
3 4 x x | 2  ->  3 4 1 2 | 2
*/
void guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsTwoAndLastTwoSkyscrapersKnown(Slice &slice)
{
    if (slice.skyscraper(3) == 3 && slice.skyscraper(2) == 4) {
        slice.insertSkyscraper(1, 1);
        slice.insertSkyscraper(2, 0);
    }
}

/*
requires:
clue = 2
4 x x x | 2 -> 4 x x 3 | 2
*/
void guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsTwoAndLastSkyscraperIsFour(Slice &slice)
{
    if (slice.skyscraper(3) == 4) {
        slice.insertSkyscraper(3, 0);
    }
}

void guessSkyscrapersOneSkyscraperIsMissing(Slice &slice)
{
    int missingValueIdx = -1;
    std::vector<int> sequence;
    sequence.reserve(slice.size() - 1);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < slice.size(); ++i) {
        if (slice.skyscraper(i) != 0) {
            sequence.emplace_back(slice.skyscraper(i));
        }
        else {
            if (missingValueIdx != -1) {
                return;
            }
            missingValueIdx = i;
        }
    }

    if (missingValueIdx != -1) {
        int n = sequence.size() + 1;
        int projectedSum = (n + 1) * (n / 2);
        int actualSum = std::accumulate(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0);
        int missingValue = projectedSum - actualSum;
        slice.insertSkyscraper(missingValue, missingValueIdx);
    }
}

std::vector<Slice> makeSlicesWithClues(Board &board,
                                       const std::array<int, 16> &clues)
{
    BorderIterator borderIterator{board.skyscrapers.size()};

    std::vector<Slice> slices;
    slices.reserve(clues.size());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < clues.size(); ++i, ++borderIterator) {
        slices.emplace_back(Slice{board, borderIterator.point(),
                                  borderIterator.borderPosition(), clues[i]});
    }
    return slices;
}

void guessSkyscrapersAndNopesFromClues(Slice &slice, int clue)
{
    if (clue == 2) {
        guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsTwoAndLastTwoSkyscrapersKnown(slice);
        guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsTwoAndLastSkyscraperIsFour(slice);
    }
    else if (clue == 3) {
        guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsThreeAndLastTwoSkyscrapersKnown(slice);
        guessSkyscrapersIfClueIsThreeAndLastSkyscraperIsFourAndThirdNopeIsThree(
            slice);
    }
}

std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4> SolvePuzzle(const std::array<int, 16> &clues)
{
    Board board{4};
    std::vector<Slice> slices = makeSlicesWithClues(board, clues);

    for (;;) {
        bool allFullFirst = true;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < slices.size() / 2; ++i) {
            if (slices[i].isFull()) {
                continue;
            }
            allFullFirst = false;

            addMissingNopesFromKnownSkyscrapers(slices[i]);
            guessSkyscrapersOneSkyscraperIsMissing(slices[i]);
            guessSkyscrapersOutOfNeighbourNopes(slices[i]);

            if (slices[i].clue() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            addMissingNopesFromKnownSkyscrapers(slices[i]);
            guessSkyscrapersAndNopesFromClues(slices[i], clues[i]);
        }

        if (allFullFirst) {
            break;
        }

        bool allFullSecond = true;
        for (std::size_t i = slices.size() / 2; i < slices.size(); ++i) {
            if (slices[i].isFull()) {
                continue;
            }
            allFullSecond = false;

            if (slices[i].clue() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            addMissingNopesFromKnownSkyscrapers(slices[i]);
            guessSkyscrapersAndNopesFromClues(slices[i], clues[i]);
        }

        if (allFullSecond) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return board.skyscrapers;
}

int **SolvePuzzle(int *clues)
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::array<int, 16> cluesArray;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        cluesArray[i] = clues[i];
    }

    auto resultArray = SolvePuzzle(cluesArray);

    int count = resultArray.size();

    int **result = new int *[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result[i] = new int[count];
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < count; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < count; ++x) {
            result[y][x] = resultArray[y][x];
        }
    }

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();

    std::cout << "duration:\t" << duration << '\n';

    return result;
}
```

Tests:

**tst_skyscrapertest.h**

```
#ifndef TST_SKYSCRAPERETEST_H
#define TST_SKYSCRAPERETEST_H

#include <gmock/gmock-matchers.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "../Skyscrapers/skyscrapers.h"

#include <array>

using namespace testing;

TEST(Skyscrapers, easy)
{
    int clues[16] = {2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3};

    int expectedResult[4][4] = {
        {1, 3, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 4}};

    auto result = SolvePuzzle(clues);

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
            EXPECT_EQ(result[y][x], expectedResult[y][x]);
        }
    }
}

TEST(Skyscrapers, easy_2)
{
    int clues[16] = {4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3};

    int expectedResult[4][4] = {
        {1, 3, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 3}};

    auto result = SolvePuzzle(clues);

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
            EXPECT_EQ(result[y][x], expectedResult[y][x]);
        }
    }
}

TEST(Skyscrapers, hard)
{
    int clues[16] = {0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};

    int expectedResult[4][4] = {
        {2, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 4}};

    auto result = SolvePuzzle(clues);

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
            EXPECT_EQ(result[y][x], expectedResult[y][x]);
        }
    }
}

TEST(Skyscrapers, hard_2)
{
    int clues[16] = {0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0};

    int expectedResult[4][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 3}};

    auto result = SolvePuzzle(clues);

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
            EXPECT_EQ(result[y][x], expectedResult[y][x]);
        }
    }
}

#endif // TST_BLAINETEST_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "tst_skyscraperstest.h"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```